# MessageLockLost: Service Bus message expires even with regular renewals

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

I'm trying to understand why Service Bus message expires even with regular renewals if task duration is longer than ~20 minutes.

I configured Service Bus receiver to work with long-running tasks. For that I start a side thread that invokes renewal every ~4 minutes (lock duration equals 5 minutes). This approach works well when processing takes **17 minutes** for example but fails for tasks with duration **20 minutes** and longer. Here is my very ordinal setup:

Receiver initialization:

```
var options = new ServiceBusReceiverOptions { ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock };
_receiver = _serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(
                messageSource.EntityName,
                messageSource.SubscriptionName,
                options);
```

Getting message:

```
    var message = await _receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Message renewal:

```
    int interval = Convert.ToInt32((message.LockedUntil - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds * 3 / 4);
    if (interval < 1)
        interval = 1;
    var timercallBack = new TimerCallback(async obj => await RenewAsync((ServiceBusReceivedMessage)obj, cancellationToken));
    var timer = new Timer(timercallBack, message, interval, interval);
```

Message renewal function:

```
private async Task RenewAsync(ServiceBusReceivedMessage msg, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _receiver.RenewMessageLockAsync(msg, cancellationToken);
    _logger.Debug($"Message {msg.MessageId}: Message processing time: {DateTime.UtcNow - msg.EnqueuedTime}. {nameof(msg.LockedUntil)}: {msg.LockedUntil}. Delivery count: {msg.DeliveryCount}.");
}
```

Message completion:

```
_logger.Debug($"Completing message {msg.Msg.MessageId}...");
await _receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(msg, cancellationToken);
```

Here are the logs:

```
25 Nov 2023 17:23:16.716: New message received..
25 Nov 2023 17:27:01.935: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:22:13.3302606. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:32:02 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:30:47.157: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:25:58.5522655. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:35:47 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:34:32.384: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:29:43.7797238. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:39:32 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:38:17.554: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:33:28.9497474. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:43:17 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:42:02.758: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:37:14.1531070. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:47:03 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:45:47.965: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:40:59.3606038. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:50:48 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:49:33.174: Message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c: Message processing time: 08:44:44.5690526. LockedUntil: 11/25/2023 2:54:33 PM +00:00. Delivery count: 10.
25 Nov 2023 17:50:16.727: Completing message 5c79f94f483c4aa58404b5a2ce8e0f3c...
25 Nov 2023 17:50:16.779: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance. (MessageLockLost). For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.
```

So every renewal operation is successful but completion attempt fails somehow. Could somebody give me a hint how to fix it?

**EDIT**: I have also tried to switch to `ServiceBusProcessor` and received the same issue.

Comment: 1. Client side lock renewal is not a guaranteed operation. 2. Try `ServiceBusProcessor` to see if you have a better luck.

Comment: @SeanFeldman thank you for you reply. After some experiments I found that it's definitely some restriction - no one operation with 21 minutes duration can be executed while ALL operations with 17 minutes can.

Comment: @SeanFeldman I have also tried to switch to ServiceBusProcessor and received the same issue for 20+ minutes tasks.

Comment: you could raise an issue with the service bus team [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).

Comment: Issue link https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/684